# How to replace all the occurences but one in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of integers of length `K`.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5]  # length here is 6
```

I would like to replace all the occurrences of each distinct value in the list by `len(a)`, except for keeping the last value intact. I have three `0`, two `1` and one `5`. So I will replace two `0` (out of three) by `6`, one `1` (out of two) by `6` and that's it.

I would get:

```
b = [6, 6, 0, 6, 1, 5]
```

The last 0, the last 1, and the last 5 are retained; the others are replaced by the list length.

I tried to do it this way:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5]
xx = [[i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == e] for e in range(len(a))]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if len(xx[i]) > 1:
        for j in range(len(xx[i]) - 1):
            a[xx[i][j]] = len(a)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this ?

Comment: all occurrences of *what?*

Comment: never mind, I asked the exact same question as Quirk. It is not obvious from your example, what the rule is supposed to be. You're replacing two zeros and a one but leaving three elements as they are. So "keep only one" what?

Comment: Is the list guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: The list is not guaranteed to be sorted. It has element from `range(len(a))` with duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be the first element, that you keep, I'd do:

```
seen = []
for i, elm in enumerate(a):
    if elm in seen:
        a[i] = len(a)
    else:
        seen.append(elm)
del seen
```

This yields

```
[0, 6, 6, 1, 6, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it. Use a dict `prev` to keep track of the index of the previous seen value. If we've seen it, then change it to 6:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5]
prev = {}
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] in prev:
        a[prev[a[i]]] = len(a)
    prev[a[i]] = i

print a
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you'd like it in a one-liner:

```
a = [len(a) if val==a[i+1] else val \
            for i, val in enumerate(a[:-1])] + [a[-1]]
```

For each element, check to see whether it equals the one after (assumes that **a** has all equal values contiguous in the list).  If so, choose the list length; otherwise, the current value.  Do this for all but the last element, which we simply concatenate.

Output:

```
[6, 6, 0, 6, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Note that this might not be what OP wanted, as with `[5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 5]`, we get `[9, 9, 5, 9, 9, 0, 9, 1, 5]`, which has a duplicated `5`.

Comment: Right -- hence the caveat about contiguity.  Using my answer, a list of alternating 1s and 0s would come out unchanged, but the others would handle that case.